# apache fails to restart...happened out of the blue :/

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, namevirtualhost

Tried navigating to my server today and noticed that NONE of my hosted websites are loading...even if I enter the ip and try to hit the default page I get nothing. I hadn't touched the server since it was working properly so I'm not sure what has happened. I made a couple little changes and tried to restart apache and whenever I try I get this:

```
jcmo:~# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
Restarting web server: apache2[Mon Jul 16 21:13:10 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Mon Jul 16 21:13:10 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts
[Mon Jul 16 21:13:10 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Mon Jul 16 21:13:10 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Mon Jul 16 21:13:10 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Mon Jul 16 21:13:10 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Mon Jul 16 21:13:10 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts
[Mon Jul 16 21:13:10 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Mon Jul 16 21:13:10 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Mon Jul 16 21:13:10 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
 failed!
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll have to check your httpd.conf or vhost configuration file and see what's happening there - maybe a stray character somewhere? Use apachectl to parse your config files and see if they're OK.

Comment: You should post the output of:

```grep VirtualHost /etc/apache2/*```

```grep VirtualHost /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*```

And any uncommented <VirtualHost> blocks (obscuring sensitive info if there is any)

Comment: Btw this is just a warning so you Apache server should still run.

Comment: Are there any relevant error messages in your error log ?

Comment: Jason is helping me and it seems that I caused this problem.  Apache was looking for a 'logs' directory in one of the sites.  I think I deleted it.  When I re-created the directory Apache started.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have still space left in the mount that holds `/var/log`? Are the log file/dir permissions OK? Too many times everything else has been fine for me, but something related to logging has bugged Apache.

Comment: There seems to be space available